# method overloading \ overriding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have a scenario, i which I have a share button, I have a container controller, called metaCtrl, which is on the html tag.

And also inner controllers.

I have a share button, that calls the model.share() function on click.

code:

```
app.controller('metaCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.share = function(){
        $location.path('/share').search({'share' : '1'});
    }
});
```

The controller of the share page it self:

```
app.controller('shareCtrl', function($scope)){
 $scope.layout.shareVisible = $location.path().share == 1 ? true : false;
    $scope.model.share = function(){
         $scope.layout.shareVisible = $scope.layout.shareVisible ? false : true;
         var shareUrlValue = $scope.layout.shareVisible ? 1 : null;

         $location.search('share', shareUrlValue);
    }
});
```

The idea is to use the same HTML pattern in the entire application, but only to toggle the share section on the share page(if the user is already there), and to send the user to the share view if he is not currently there.

The problem is that after I go to the sahre page, and then return to the other page, the function share() has a referance to the function in the shareCtrl, rather then to the metaCtrl.

Comment: Could you give more information? What's your html like? What's your routeProvider config like?

Comment: The meta controller is on the HTML tag, and the other controller is view specific one, from the router.

Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: I believe angular runs the controller function defined in routing configuration, so you have to think another way. If I understood your problem correctly, you might consider using an interceptor on route change, and redirect to share page if the user needs to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's enough information here, but I'll take a shot at it (I can't comment because I don't have enough rep).  Notice that your shareCtrl is not creating a new model object, you're just assigning $scope.model.share = func....

That assignment is overriding the function in the parent controller because Angular is going up the scope chain to find the model object.

See this Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yv5rrpdlkniZdg94T4Lf

Notice with $scope.model = {} commented out in shareCtrl, the value of both fields is "shareCtrl".  But, if you uncomment that line, then $scope.model is within the shareCtrl scope so Angular doesn't go up the scope chain looking.

Comment: The access from the child controller to the parent controller in AngularJS is read-only

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  Take a look at my Plunker in a debugger.  You can see the prototype of the shareCtrl $scope object is the metaCtrl $scope object.  Since you're not creating a 'model' property on the shareCtrl $scope object, the assignment is going to the prototype's 'model' property.

Comment: I am saying that there is no way to modify the parent scope from a child scope in angular

Comment: Not true.  Try it in my plunker.

Comment: Checking.

The way I read that it is, is that you can create a member in the same name of a member in the parent scope.
But once you'll be out of that scope, the reference will be to the parent scope.